# Playing with stack and values of variables

Tags: c, memory

I'm playing with stack and variadic function - I don't want to use `va_arg`. Here's my code:

```
void myfunc(char* string, ...) {
  char* args;

  args = (char*) &string + sizeof(string); // point to first parameter, and then point to the second one

  while (*string != '\0') {
    if (*string == '%') {
        int address = (*((int*) args)); // address of parameter
        args += sizeof(int);
        int* point = (int*)address;
        *point = 'g';
    }
   *string++;
  }
  free(buffer);
}

int main(void) {
  char k = 't';
  char j = 'j';
  char l = 'l';
  char c = 'p';
  printf("address of c in main %p \n",  &c);
  printf("address of k in main %p \n",  &k);
  myfunc("%d %d", &c, &k);
  printf("c: %c\nj: %c\n", c, j);
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it somehow erases other variables values and I don't know why. Ok, I suppose there must be some error with memory etc. but I'm not sure what's wrong - it looks like it gets valid addresses of memory (I checked by `printf`).
Here's the output:

```
address of c in main 0xffa52a25 
address of k in main 0xffa52a24 
w func 0xffa52a24
w func 0xffa52a25
c: g
j:
```

And yes, I know this isn't portable and all, I'm well aware of it.

Comment: Why are you passing in pointers to `char`, and then treating them as pointers to `int`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters if we take the address as `int *` or `char *` and I have troubles dealing with `char*` here.

Comment: Why are you dereferencing `args` in `myfunc()`?  I'm assuming that you want `address` to be the address of `args`, treated as an integer?  Dereferencing it won't do that--it'll just grab the first `sizeof(int)` bytes at `args` and put it in `address`.  You can cast a pointer to an integer type directly.

The thing to be careful of is that, depending on your system, an `int` may not be big enough to hold a pointer.  In particular, on many 64-bit systems and runtime environments/memory models (including the ones used on Windows and most Unix(ish) systems), `int` is 32 bits wide.

Comment: @KurtWeber so you're saying I should do `int address = (int*) args`? I don't know if I understood, now  don't get correct addresses of variables in `myfunc`. Maybe I should use `char*` instead but when I tried bad things happend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
myfunc("%d %d", &c, &k);
```

you give the addresses of two `char` variables to your function, but inside of it you write an `int` into the memory pointed to:

```
int* point = (int*)address;
*point = 'g';
```

The character `'g'` will be stored as an `int` that takes more bytes than a `char`, overwriting what is following in memory. And there are the other variables...